# Angular 4 Reponse Headers not setting all values

Tags: angular

In angular 4 application , I am receiving HTTP response via CORS web-services. But angular 4 **(version 4.3.0)** response object just setting content-type and ignoring other in Promise.then(response) response object.

Here is the response headers I receive in Chrome Developer Tool network tab.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization

Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Connection:Keep-Alive

Content-Encoding:gzip

Content-Length:20

Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8

Date:Thu, 20 Jul 2017 04:08:10 GMT

Keep-Alive:timeout=3, max=26

Authorization:xyzpqrmnoabc

Vary:Authorization,Accept-Encoding

X-Powered-By:Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (Tomcat/8.5 JRE/1.7)
```

Here is Headers object taken from Response object that just contains and missing other headers.

```
{"Content-Type":["application/json;charset=utf-8"]}
```

**Is it due to Promise, response headers are not setting correctly?
Do I need to move to Observables?**

```
postData(data: any): Promise<object> {
                return this.http
                    .post(this.url, data, this.options)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then((response) => { return this.handleSuccess(response); })
                    .catch((exce) => { return this.handleError(exce); });
            }

handleSuccess(res: Response): Promise<Array<any>> {
            console.log('RESPONSE : ',res); // not contain full headers
            let hdrs: Headers = new Headers(res['headers']); // not contain full headers
            console.log('*** HEADERS', JSON.stringify(hdrs.toJSON())); // not contain full headers
            return Promise.resolve(res.json());
    }
```

Comment: What is the complete headers object in your response object? What is your HTTP trigger code?

Comment: in chrome developer tools I receive above full response. but headers in my response object just contains Content-Type

Comment: Ok. try observables of Http.get/post etc. This is the header spec - nothing much to it https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#headers-class .Can I see the http method and trigger even if you are unable to get headers from observables?

Comment: @Gary Updated with HTTP trigger code and response handling method

Answer (score 0):

Try this observable and see the result -

This is a function below:

```
postData(data: any){
    return this.http.post(this.url, data, this.options);                
}
```

May be you can also try this promise way:

This is a function below:

```
postData(data: any){
    return this.http.post(this.url, data, this.options).toPromise();                
}
```

Use it like this somewhere in your code:

```
this.postData(data).subscribe((res)=>{
   console.log(res); 
   // This should have all headers along with statusCode and status
})
```

or for promises

```
this.postData(data).then((res)=>{
       console.log(res); 
       // This should have all headers along with statusCode and status
    }, (err)=>{
       console.log(err); 
       // This should have all headers along with statusCode and status
    })
```

Comment: I have tried this, but not working for me for **import { Http } from '@angular/http'**
I will implement **import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';** then I will check.I am not sure why there are 2 implementation for http.

Comment: hmm...what version of ng are you using? It works for me with 4.3.1. Any outdated version of API will always be in angular for two version cycles.